# SQL LINQ Select title and list that belongs to that title

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have some tables for working with menus, first is MenuOfTheWeek where I have the following information:

```
menuOfTheWeekId, menuId, isMenuOfTheWeek, timestamp
```

I also have table Menu with:

```
menuId, userId
```

and table MenuRecipes with:

```
menuRecipesId, menuId, recipeId
```

I wan`t to select menu title and list of recipes that are in that menu. I was writing select something like

```
var result = context.Menu
             .Where(x => x.MenuOfTheWeek.Where(mw => mw.isMenuOfTheWeek == true))
             .Select(x => new
             {
                 title = x.MenuTranslation.FirstOrDefault().title,
                 List<Recipe> menuRecipes = x.MenuRecipes ...
             };
```

In Recipe class I have stored all the data for recipe (title, ImagePath, rating, prepTime...). What is the best way for selecting this list of recipes, maybe is better that I don`t use my Recipe class(use of this class is not necesary)...

I once manage some similar thing with LinqDataSource and write select there like

```
Select="new (key as title, it as MenuRecipes, Count() as Count)" and GroupBy...
```

and than with nested listview I can put the MenuRecipes as DataSource. This works fine, but I am sure that I can also write that with LINQ in codebehind and I also wan`t to learn some new things about these selects ...

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = (from p in context.MenuOfTheWeekSet
    .Include("MenuRecipes")
    .Include("Recipe")
    where p.isMenuOfTheWeek
    select p.Menu).FirstOrDefault();

foreach (MenuRecipes r in result.MenuRecipes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r.Recipe.recipeId);
}
```

[image: Model]

Assuming your model is like in the picture. Then something like this should do the trick. Then you would have the menu and you could access the recipes for that menu.

Comment: Yes model on your picture is o.k. Thank you for your help I can manage to select the data that I wan`t but your answer is not quite what I Want... because I know that you can with group by select title as key an list of recipes in one piece. But with your solution I need to select all MenuRecipes, that with database connections get the data that I need - that requires from me one foreach and one select for title (but group by will do that for me)... But thank you  for your help, you give me idea how to temporary solve my problem

Comment: I am uncertain why you want to have them (title + menurecipes) as anonymous type? You can also include the MenuTranslation to the query if that was missing.